# storing and retrieving id from service

Tags: angular

I would like to store the value of currentStudentId in my service once I have gotten it from my database, such that it can be accessed from multiple components throughout my app by calling getCurrentStudentId().

I am getting confused because the actual student object (containing the id) is returned as a promise from my database and I am not sure how to convert that. What I want to do is this (service):

```
currentStudentId: string;

getCurrentStudentId(): string {

    if( this.currentStudentId ) {
        console.log("Great, the id is already set. Let's simply return it!");
        return this.currentStudentId;
    }
    else {
        console.log("The id isn't set yet, so need to get the student from the db first");
        this.getStudentCurrent(); // I get the student from the db and return it as a promise

        // return ???
    }
    return ???
}
```

My question is what do I need to return in this function?

Comment: a promise is used for async computing. ie it is an action with often an anon function to handle the success. To make a promise synchronous you can use `await` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await
So: `await this.getStudentCurrent();`

Comment: if you aren't using async/await - just return a promise wrapping the student id.

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb is to make your function asynchronous if it has any asynchronous calls within it. So you need to change the return type to `Promise<string>` like this

```
getCurrentStudentId(): Promise<string> {
    if(this.currentStudentId) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.currentStudentId); // wrap cached value in promise
    }

    return this.getStudentCurrent()
       .then(currentStudent => {
            this.currentStudentId = currentStudent.id;
            return this.currentStudentId;
       });
}
```

Or using `async/await`

```
async getCurrentStudentId(): Promise<string> {
    if(this.currentStudentId) {
        return this.currentStudentId;
    }

    let currentStudent = await this.getStudentCurrent();
    this.currentStudentId = currentStudent.id;

    return this.currentStudentId;
}
```